# if we send an array list of objects into the database, then can we get the same ordered list while retrieving from database?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am sending an array list of objects into the database in some order, so can i get the same ordered list while fetching from the database. If order is not same, What might be the reason?

Here is some sample code:

```
List<Branch> branchList = new ArrayList<Branch>();
Branch branch = new Branch();
branch.setName("branch1");
barnch.setId(2);
branchList.add(branch);
branch  = new Branch();
banch.setName("branch2");
barnch.setId(1);
branchList.add(branch);

Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
tenant.setName("StackOverFlow");
tenant.setListBranches(branchList);
dataStoreService.put(tenant); //put into the database.
```

Comment: Please let **me** know what is happening at database side.

Comment: You show some code, we show some answers, because without code, the answer is: It depends.

Comment: This will of course depend on *what database* you use...

Comment: Are you using an arbitrary order or can you sort your list once you retrieve it to restore its original order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. The database organizes stored data in a way that is optimal for data retrieval. The list that is inserted into the database will be placed into a data structure (typically a [B+ Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) for common databases).

This data structure will not remember which order the data was inserted.

If you are keen to retrieve your data in the same order that you put it in, you could assign a surrogate key to your table (which will assign IDs incrementally in the same order as it is inserted if configured correctly) or attach a timestamp to each row that you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, rows in a table in a relational database have no order. A particular relational database implementation may happen to save rows physically in storage in the order created, and may even return them to you in that order, but you should *never* count on that behavior.

Define a column on which you want to sort. As part of your query include an ORDER BY.